# SAM format: Does the BAM "Integer or numeric array" field no longer exist? Why?

Tags: sam, samtools, htslib

The SAM file format specification makes clear that optional fields must follow the format `TAG:TYPE:VALUE`

```
Type   Regexp matching                                       VALUE Description
A     [!-~]                                                  Printable character
i     [-+]?[0-9]+                                            Signed integer
f     [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?                 Single-precision floating number
Z     [ !-~]*                                                Printable string, including space
H     ([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])*                                    Byte array in the Hex format10
B     [cCsSiIf](,[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)+    Integer or numeric array
```

However, looking at the samtools source code, I noticed this:

https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/sam_view.c#L920-L931

```
switch (aux_type) {
    case 'H':
    case 'Z':
        if (kputs(bam_aux2Z(s), linebuf) < 0) return false;
        break;
    case 'i': kputw(bam_aux2i(s), linebuf); break;
    case 'I': kputuw(bam_aux2i(s), linebuf); break;
    case 'A': kputc(bam_aux2A(s), linebuf); break;
    case 'f': kputd(bam_aux2f(s), linebuf); break;
    case 'B': kputs("*** Unhandled aux type ***", linebuf); return false;
    default:  kputs("*** Unknown aux type ***", linebuf); return false;
}
```

Questions:

(1) I have never seen an "Integer or numeric array" of `case "B"`. What does such an tag look like? Is there an example?

(2) Why is this currently `"*** Unhandled aux type ***"`? Was this the case with previous versions of samtools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An example would be `ZC:B:i,271,271,1,0`, which is from TMAP. The `i` part denotes the values held in the array, which are comma-separated.
2. That code is only used in `samtools fastq`, where that tag type isn't output into fastq files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. "which is from TMAP"---where did you find this?

Comment: Also, how command is this tag? I don't think I've seen this type of tag "in the wild" in any BAM files....though perhaps I'm very wrong.

Comment: That particular example can be found [here](https://wabi-wiki.scilifelab.se/display/KB/TMAP). You don't see tags like this that frequently, I had to search for a concrete example since I don't recall seeing any locally in a few years.

Comment: Last questions: (1) I haven't seen this either. Is there any evidence that this tag format has largely been abandoned in recent years? (2) Is there a reason why the tag isn't output into FASTQ files?

Comment: That's used under the hood if you have more than 65535 CIGAR operations, but otherwise hasn't really seen wide-spread use. I guess no one ever saw the point in outputting that in fastq files. Presumably someone could make a PR to add it.

Comment: "if you have more than 65535 CIGAR operations" Could you detail this a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to detail there. Really long noisy reads can result in a lot of CIGAR operations, which exceed the bounds of the actual CIGAR field in a BAM file. Thus the `CG` auxiliary tag, which is also an array at its core.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed a further clarification. I think I understand now, thank you